# Increase number of terms shown in termstore

Tags: term-store

Are there any way to edit the default limit of ten terms in the termstore view?

[image]

Comment: Yes, with PowerShell :-)

Comment: Hi, just curious, have you seen my answer? :)

Comment: @VadimGremyachev I have, I will start working with that solution during friday, I'll keep you posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Tree` JavaScript control (`treecontrol.js`) is intended for rendering Taxonomy tree control. Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Tree  `PageLimit` property defines *the number of visible terms*.

You could consider the following solution *to override* default (10) `PageLimit` property value:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Tree.prototype.set_pageLimit(15);
}, 
'treecontrol.js');
```

The example demonstrates how to make `15` terms visible when TermSet is expanded.

In order to apply the changes per web/site:

- Save the specified code into `treecontrol.settings.js` file and upload it into for example into `Style Library`
- Reference the specified file in master page

> The solution is compatible with SharePoint 2010/2013 and Online versions

**Result**

[image]

Comment: This looks like it is in Site settings > Term store management. Does this also work in the controls that users see? Can it be expanded to realistic limits like 50?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar to what Vadim suggested in order to fix the modal dialog box when users are editing metadata fields.

NOTE: for Sharepoint 2013

put a file in styles library like: `custom.sharepoint.behaviours.js`

contents:

```
/* belongs in styles library */
function CustomSPBehaviours() {
//  console.debug(["custom.sharepoint.behaviours", Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy]);
  if(typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Tree)=='undefined')
    return;
  Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.Tree.prototype.set_pageLimit(30);
};
SP.SOD.executeFunc('treecontrol.js', 'SP.ClientContext', CustomSPBehaviours);
```

add this line before the ending body tag of `master.template`

```
<script type="text/javascript"; src="/sites/mysharepointsite/Style%20Library/custom.sharepoint.behaviours.js"></script>
```

add the same line to the file (prior to the last ending `asp:content tag`)

```
c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\WebTaggingDialog.aspx
```

the WebTaggingdialog change is needed because the Term Set Picker is a modal dialog box that initalizes treecontrol

In my situation I had a bunch of hidden terms and the paginations were returning only a few selectable items as the hidden terms were taking up the remaining spots...